# A markdown editor similar to StackOverflow built-in post-editor

Tags: text-editor, markdown

Is there any text/MD editor close to StackOverflow post with MD + embedded code snippet
for taking notes and documenting? (as well for teaching)

- low file-size
- live preview
- offline
- lightweight

Comment: Which OS ? Free or not? Important: are you interesting in displaying math formula? (The Achilles heel of most MD editors). Are you interested in the possibility to convert the MD file in html only, or also pdf, docx, odt formats? Note that some editors rely on an external powerfull software (generally *pandoc*), not so light, to perform such conversions ... I am currently in the process to select such an editor (for liinux), have tested about 10 editors .... no one is perfect, best choice depends on your real needs...

Comment: @Damien I use Windows, well I'd like to have math formulas but since I'm gonna use it for documenting programming, then that won't be an anchor bolt. Well all options you said are positive for everyone, but the most important features are what I already have mentioned: MarkDown + run code in the document just like StackOverflow post-editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor

You can see a preview of this editor here: https://editor.stackoverflow.design/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Two examples would be:

[Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/)

[Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/)

Both can do TeX-like math notation I believe. I think there is no Markdown editor that allows you to "run code" in it though, but they allow formatting code as such, even with language-specific syntax highlighting.

There's also [HackMD](https://hackmd.io/#) but that seems more aimed at online collaboration.

If anyone knows other good alternatives, especially cross-platform ones, I'm interested to know.